# Listen to local variable changes via inner function

Tags: javascript, closures

```js
function init() {
  var name = "Breaking Bad";
  function getName() {
    console.log(name);
  }
  function setName(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  return {
    getName: getName,
    setName: setName
  };
}

const sayMyName = init().getName; // during initialization
init().setName('Heisenberg'); // can be updated multiple times later
sayMyName(); // isn't latest i.e. NOT Heisenberg
```

What can be done so that `getName` gets the latest `name` ?

PS: I tried, but couldn't find a solution on stackoverflow after reading many answers on inner functions, closures etc.

Comment: When ever you call `init()`, you are returning a new object. So it will always give you initial value. If you explain what you wish to achieve, we could help you with alternate solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> PS: I tried, but couldn't find a solution on stackoverflow after
>   reading many answers on inner functions, closures etc.

Because when you did

```
init().setName('Heisenberg');
```

you ended up setting the name to a different reference of `init()` as every time you invoke `init` it will return a different reference of `getName` and `setName`.

Make it

```js
function init() {
  var name = "Breaking Bad";
  function getName() {
    console.log(name);
  }
  function setName(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  return {
    getName: getName,
    setName: setName
  };
}
var init1 = init(); //save the initialization
var sayMyName = init1.getName; 
init1.setName('Heisenberg'); // can be updated multiple times later
sayMyName();
```

Comment: I took the liberty of converting your code sample to a runnable snippet. Just a tip, when a question contains a snippet you can click the "Copy snippet to answer" button so it will also be a snippet in your answer.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks, I was about to do the same anyways :)